# Spring Migration to 5.3.19 from 4.3.29 issue with .binding files

Tags: spring, binding, ibm-mq, jndi, spring-jms

I have started my migration of spring version from 4.3.29.RELEASE to 5.3.29 I have fixed some of the issues with servlet and AbstractClientHttpRequest files but I was facing some issue with .binding files, I see they were loading as part of application context after migrating the spring version to 5.3.19 , with the older version of Spring 4.3.29.RELEASE I was able to bring up my application with out any issues. Now with 5.3.19 when I start my application I am getting below issue.

```
03-May-2022 10:11:00.537 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'TestMgmtDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'editorService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'editorService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'trentonMessagePublisher'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trentonMessagePublisher' defined in class path resource [config/queue-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jmsTemplate' while setting bean property 'jmsTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [config/queue-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'connectionFactory' while setting bean property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [config/queue-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'testConnectionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [config/queue-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [TEST_QMGR_QCF] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [TEST_QMGR_QCF].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [config/queue-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [TEST_QMGR_QCF] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [TEST_QMGR_QCF].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myTestQueue' defined in class path resource [config/queue-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [Q_OUTBOUND_TEST.CHECK_TO_QUEUETON] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [Q_OUTBOUND_TEST.CHECK_TO_QUEUETON].
```

My Sample .binding file is below , I am using IBM MQ.

```
TEST_QMGR_QCF/RefAddr/1/Type=XXX
TEST_QMGR_QCF/RefAddr/2/Content=XXXX
TEST_QMGR_QCF/RefAddr/3/Content=TEST.TEST.TLS
TEST_QMGR_QCF/RefAddr/4/Content=true
TEST_QMGR_QCF/RefAddr/5/Content=0
TEST_QMGR_QCF/RefAddr/9/Type=TCM
TEST_QMGR_QCF/RefAddr/91/Type=TM
```

Version of the the IBM Mq jar files used are.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.2.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

I have com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory entry to to load my .binding files in my beans.xml like below.

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">file:///C:/Local</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="umConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="TEST_QMGR_QCF"/>
</bean>
```

This is where I see with older version of Spring I was able to load the .bindings but with upgrade unable to load.

Comment: @Joshmc can you check this once

Comment: How are you referencing your .binding file?

Comment: We were adding the .bindings file in the class path , that is being loaded from the application context while server comes up, it was good till version 4.3.29.RELEASE once I have migrated to 5.3.19 bindings were not being loaded and I started receiving exception as mentioned in the post.

Comment: CLASSPATH has nothing to do with finding the bindings file,  somewhere you need to configure where the bindings file is located.

Comment: The error message says `Unable to find [UM_QMGR_QCF]`, but your code (`.bindings` and `beans.xml`) shows name `TEST_QMGR_QCF`. There is a mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring ?

Comment: HI Daniel, I have so many queue names and I haven't added the full stack trace to the issue...I am getting the same error for TEST_QMGR_QCF as well, I have update my original post with proper Exception details.

Comment: Hi Chughts, We are working on migration and this https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring    requires a complete re-write.

Answer (score 1):

The best that I can do is to try to point you in the right direction.  The `.bindings` file uses the `com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory` to provide a JNDI like lookup that is initialized from your `.bindings` file.

You can find some references here [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/imdm/11.6?topic=file-creating-bindings-unix) and [Sun](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19340-01/820-6767/aeqbb/index.html).

Note that the jar files `fscontext.jar` and `providerutil.jar` are provided with the IBM MQ distribution in the `/opt/mqm/java/lib` directory.  These are the Sun jars needed for the file system context.  These files are not, however, provided by the `com.ibm.mq.allclient` maven artifact.

These jars must have been provided in your older version.  You can find them in Maven Central:

```
<groupId>com.sun.messaging.mq</groupId>
<artifactId>fscontext</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>4.6-b01</version>
```

Note that the two jars seem to have been merged into the one jar in this artifact.  Ensure that these Sun classes are in your current project.

Then, you'll need to find where you are doing something like (from the Sun link):

```
//  Create the environment for constructing the initial JNDI 
//  naming context.
Hashtable  env = new Hashtable();
    
//  Store the environment attributes that tell JNDI which initial context
//  factory to use  and where to find the provider.// 
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
                "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:///C:/imq_admin_objects");
    
//  Create the initial context.
Context  ctx = new InitialContext(env);
    
//  Look up the connection factory object in the JNDI object store.
String  CF_LOOKUP_NAME = "MyConnectionFactory";
ConnectionFactory  myFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup
                                      (CF_LOOKUP_NAME);
```

in your code.  Note that the `.bindings` file name is expected, and that the location specified is a directory where the `.bindings` file is located.

Comment: HI Doug Grove, Thanks for the inputs I already have the dependency fscontext with version 4.4.2 , Now I have added providerutil-1.2.1.jar as well I still see issue to load my .binding file...

Comment: Did you find in the code where the file system context is being called?  What is the `Context.PROVIDER_URL`?